# Caching is orthogonal to recursion... Explain?

Tags: c, networking, caching, recursion, nameservers

> Although it's true that some
>   recursive-nameserver configurations
>   are (sloppily) referred to as
>   "caching", e.g., by
>   RHEL/Fedora/CentOS, that's a really
>   bad name for that function -- because
>   caching is orthogonal to recursion.
>
> Theoretically, you could write a
>   nameserver that does recursive service
>   but doesn't cache its results. (That
>   would be a bit perverse, and I don't
>   know of any.) Conversely, nameserver
>   packages that cache but know nothing
>   about how to recurse and instead do
>   less-helpful alternative iterative
>   service are common: dnsmasq, pdnsd,
>   etc. ... ...

Above text source: http://linuxgazette.net/170/lan.html

Please explain what does the author means by "caching is orthogonal to recursion" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> caching is orthogonal to recursion?

Caching doesn't require/imply recursion.

The term "orthogonal" is meant to be interpreted from a mathematical sense loosely has "the things have nothing in common i.e. separate concepts".

Comment: how can both caching and recursion be used together for searching purposes?

Comment: Theoretically we can have a function/service which uses both caching and recursion, like a nameserver. If nothing is common, I am not able to comprehend then how they are used together?

Answer (score 2):

From Wikipedia's [definition of orthogonal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality#Computer_science):

> For example, a car has orthogonal
>   components and controls (e.g.
>   accelerating the vehicle does not
>   influence anything else but the
>   components involved exclusively with
>   the acceleration function).

The author is saying that whether a nameserver caches is nothing to do with whether it can recurse.

Answer (score 0):

It mean it is one feature is independent with the other one. Or have bothe feature have no influence with the other one. So they can be implemented independantly

in a programming point of view, two orthogonal features

```
do_work(bool feature1, bool feature2)
{
  // do common work

  if(feature1)
  { //... do this }

   // do common work

  if(feature2)
  { // do work }

  // do common work
}
```

or: if they are not orthogonal:

you need to do this: ( and it may have case where you cant combine the two feature.

```
do_work(bool feature1, bool feature2)
{
  if(not feature1 and feature 2)
  { //... do this }

  else if(feature1 and not feature2)
  { // do work }

  // else impossible or different behavior
  // etc..
}
```